# Fortigate - Redirecting subdomains only?

Tags: dns, fortigate

I'm trying to figure out a way to have our Fortigate 60C redirect certain subdomains but not block complete access to the domain.

E.G. I want to block update.microsoft.com but I don't want microsoft.com or office.microsoft.com to be blocked.

My current settings are blocking the complete domain. I do find this strange though as I specified a hostname.

```
config system dns-database 

edit "test" 

config dns-entry 

edit 2 

set hostname "update" 

set ip 1.1.1.1 

next

end

set domain "microsoft.com"
```

My goals is to prevent certain software from accessing certain urls to prevent devices from downloading updates or phoning home.

1.1.1.1 is set as a loopback.

Blocking access on devices itself is not an option.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you would want to use a "DNS Filter" for this. It has an option to block domains via a "Static Domain Filter". In it, you can specify any combination of subdomains, which will be easier to manage than the `dns-database` option. Then, you can apply the DNS Filter to any relevant IPv4 Policy objects which should block access to those respective domains.

For example (shown from OS 5.6):

```
config dnsfilter domain-filter
    edit 0
        set name "block-updates"
        config entries
            edit 1
                set domain "updates.microsoft.com"
                set action block
            next
        end
    next
end
```

Note what ID number is created from the above block, and use it as `<id>` in the block below. (And note that tab expansion will also work.)

```
config dnsfilter profile
    edit "Block Updates"
        config domain-filter
            set domain-filter-table <id>
        end
    next
end
```

It's a bit easier to configure in the GUI, as there's no back and forth between the domain list and the profile.

Then enable it on one or more policies:

```
config firewall policy
    edit <id>
        set utm-status enable
        set dnsfilter-profile "Block Updates"
    next
end
```